# Can I say VAR is a prediction report?

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk

We use Algorithmics RiskWatch where portfolios are analyzed by VaR over scenarios. Can I say that they are predictions reports? or descriptions reports?

Comment: Do you mean the report containing a list of pairs (portfolio name, single VaR number)?

Comment: You might want to clarify what "VaR over scenarios" means. What is a list of (or maybe just examples) of "scenarios".

Comment: There is nothing predictive about VaR

Answer (score 1):

They are neither predictive or descriptive, but proscriptive it is a pre-emptive warning of the worst case scenario, of which you are being given notice to take action to avoid. It is risk management.